# CSV files - How do I replace a row of data through user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a CSV file where it stores a book, its author and the year it was published. I then made it where the program will display the file's data as a list to the user. I want to now ask the user to select a row and replace it with a different set of data. I then want this data back to the original CSV file, overwriting the existing data with the amended one. How can I do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
import csv

with open("Books.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["", "Book", "Author", "Year released"])

    writer.writerow([0, "To kill a Mockingbird", "Harper Lee", "1960"])
    writer.writerow([1, "A Brief History of Time", "Stephan Hawking", "1988"])
    writer.writerow([2, "The Great Gatsby", "F.Scott Fitzgerald", "1922"])
    writer.writerow([3, "The Man Who Mistook His Wife For a Hat", "Oliver Sacks", "1985"])
    writer.writerow([4, "Pride and Prejudice", "Jane Austen", "1813"])

books = []

with open("books.csv", "r", newline="") as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file2)
    for row in reader:
        count, book, author, year_released = row
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the file in as a list. Then modify that list. Then write that list back to disk.

```
import csv

with open("Books.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["", "Book", "Author", "Year released"])

    writer.writerow([0, "To kill a Mockingbird", "Harper Lee", "1960"])
    writer.writerow([1, "A Brief History of Time", "Stephan Hawking", "1988"])
    writer.writerow([2, "The Great Gatsby", "F.Scott Fitzgerald", "1922"])
    writer.writerow([3, "The Man Who Mistook His Wife For a Hat", "Oliver Sacks", "1985"])
    writer.writerow([4, "Pride and Prejudice", "Jane Austen", "1813"])

books = []

with open("books.csv", "r", newline="") as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file2)
    books = list(reader)

print(*books, sep='\n')

line = input("select line: ")
title = input("title: ")
author = input("author: ")
year = input("year: ")

books[int(line) + 1] = [line, title, author, year]

with open("Books.csv", 'w', newline="") as file3:
    writer = csv.writer(file3)
    writer.writerows(books)

print(*books, sep='\n')
```